# Ffmpeg same command, different results local vs server. Video shakes, invalid dropping

Tags: video, ffmpeg, ubuntu-10.04, encoding, h.264

I am trying to concat some files without reencode so I use

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy out.mp4
```

On local it works perfect but on a dedicated server video shakes! Is like video is frozen for few ms.

Besides I have an output of 1900 lines like these:

```
DTS -118059162071706656, next:2581328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071705632, next:2581328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
```

What is the problem? Do I need to install something else in ffmpeg?
Here you can see both output and see too ffmpeg configuration. Hope you can help me. Thanks.

Local, iMac, Mac OS 10.9.5:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i tmp/listVideos.txt -c copy /Users/mikel/Desktop/mergedVideo.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.7.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
  configuration: --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libfaac --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-shared --disable-mmx --arch=x86_64 --cpu=core2 --enable-libx264 --enable-static
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f877882f200] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'tmp/listVideos.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 78 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 75 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 3 kb/s
[mp4 @ 0x7f87788a8800] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x7f87788a8800] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Output #0, mp4, to '/Users/mikel/Desktop/mergedVideo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 75 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, 3 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f877882f200] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
    Last message repeated 3 times
frame=  339 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     117kB time=00:00:14.20 bitrate=  67.6kbits/s    
video:100kB audio:6kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 11.027882%
```

Server, Ubuntu 14.04

```
    ffmpeg -f concat -i tmp/listVideos.txt -c copy /home/mikel/mergedVideo.mp4
ffmpeg version N-74248-g107026e Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      54. 30.100 / 54. 30.100
  libavcodec     56. 56.101 / 56. 56.101
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 32.100 /  5. 32.100
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x2545f20] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'tmp/listVideos.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 78 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 75 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 3 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Output #0, mp4, to '/home/mikel/mergedVideo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 75 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, 3 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x25480c0] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
DTS -118059162071706656, next:2581328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071705632, next:2581328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -118059162071706144, next:2621328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071703584, next:2621328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768897152, next:2752000 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768897152, next:2752000 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071705632, next:2661328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071704608, next:2661328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768896128, next:2773333 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768896128, next:2773333 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768895104, next:2794666 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768895104, next:2794666 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071705120, next:2701328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071705120, next:2701328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768894080, next:2815999 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768894080, next:2815999 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768893056, next:2837332 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768893056, next:2837332 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071704608, next:2741328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071704096, next:2741328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768892032, next:2858665 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768892032, next:2858665 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768891008, next:2879998 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768891008, next:2879998 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071704096, next:2781328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071701536, next:2781328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768889984, next:2901331 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768889984, next:2901331 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768888960, next:2922664 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768888960, next:2922664 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071703584, next:2821328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071702560, next:2821328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768887936, next:2943997 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768887936, next:2943997 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768886912, next:2965330 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768886912, next:2965330 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071703072, next:2861328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071703072, next:2861328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768885888, next:2986663 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768885888, next:2986663 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768884864, next:3007996 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768884864, next:3007996 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071702560, next:2901328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071702048, next:2901328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768883840, next:3029329 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768883840, next:3029329 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768882816, next:3050662 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768882816, next:3050662 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071702048, next:2941328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071699488, next:2941328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768881792, next:3071995 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768881792, next:3071995 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071701536, next:2981328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071700512, next:2981328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768880768, next:3093328 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768880768, next:3093328 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768879744, next:3114661 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768879744, next:3114661 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071701024, next:3021328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071701024, next:3021328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768878720, next:3135994 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768878720, next:3135994 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768877696, next:3157327 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768877696, next:3157327 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071700512, next:3061328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071700000, next:3061328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768876672, next:3178660 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768876672, next:3178660 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768875648, next:3199993 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768875648, next:3199993 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071700000, next:3101328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071697440, next:3101328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768874624, next:3221326 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768874624, next:3221326 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768873600, next:3242659 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768873600, next:3242659 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071699488, next:3141328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071698464, next:3141328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768872576, next:3263992 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768872576, next:3263992 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768871552, next:3285325 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768871552, next:3285325 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071698976, next:3181328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071698976, next:3181328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768870528, next:3306658 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768870528, next:3306658 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768869504, next:3327991 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768869504, next:3327991 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071698464, next:3221328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071697952, next:3221328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768868480, next:3349324 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768868480, next:3349324 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768867456, next:3370657 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768867456, next:3370657 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071697952, next:3261328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071695392, next:3261328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768866432, next:3391990 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768866432, next:3391990 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071697440, next:3301328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071696416, next:3301328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768865408, next:3413323 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768865408, next:3413323 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768864384, next:3434656 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768864384, next:3434656 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071696928, next:3341328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071696928, next:3341328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768863360, next:3455989 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768863360, next:3455989 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768862336, next:3477322 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768862336, next:3477322 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071696416, next:3381328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071695904, next:3381328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768861312, next:3498655 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768861312, next:3498655 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768860288, next:3519988 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768860288, next:3519988 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071695904, next:3421328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071693344, next:3421328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768859264, next:3541321 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768859264, next:3541321 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768858240, next:3562654 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768858240, next:3562654 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071695392, next:3461328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071694368, next:3461328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768857216, next:3583987 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768857216, next:3583987 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768856192, next:3605320 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768856192, next:3605320 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071694880, next:3501328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071694880, next:3501328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768855168, next:3626653 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768855168, next:3626653 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768854144, next:3647986 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768854144, next:3647986 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071694368, next:3541328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071693856, next:3541328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768853120, next:3669319 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768853120, next:3669319 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768852096, next:3690652 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768852096, next:3690652 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071693856, next:3581328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071691296, next:3581328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768851072, next:3711985 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768851072, next:3711985 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071693344, next:3621328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071692320, next:3621328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768850048, next:3733318 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768850048, next:3733318 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768849024, next:3754651 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768849024, next:3754651 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071692832, next:3661328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071692832, next:3661328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768848000, next:3775984 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768848000, next:3775984 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768846976, next:3797317 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768846976, next:3797317 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071692320, next:3701328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071691808, next:3701328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768845952, next:3818650 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768845952, next:3818650 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -442721857768844928, next:3839983 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768844928, next:3839983 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -118059162071691808, next:3741328 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -118059162071689248, next:3741328 invalid dropping st:0
[mp4 @ 0x25cb340] pts has no value
DTS -442721857768843904, next:3861316 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -442721857768843904, next:3861316 invalid dropping st:1
// ------------  DELETED 1700 lines as above  ----------------------
frame=  339 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     115kB time=00:00:14.20 bitrate=  66.4kbits/s    
video:100kB audio:6kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 9.041476%
```

Comment: Are those the exactly same videos? DTS/PTS errors point to corrupt video files.

Comment: Yes, I previously convert all videos with `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "fps=fps=25, scale=1280:720" -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset fast -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -ac 2  output.mp4`. You can [see videos info](http://i.imgur.com/AkNNBZu.png)

Comment: Could be a difference in ffmpeg versions? There is no guarantee of consistent behavior between versions. Consider changing the versions around just to see if the behavior changes on either the Mac or Ubuntu. As was already mentioned you may want to verify that the server video is correct.